# How do you turn the exit status of a program into the signal name

Tags: linux, signals

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *status, int options);
```

For example when the status=2, return the string "SIGINT" when the status=11, return the string "SIGSEGV".
Is there a built_in c function that takes in the status and outputs the signal name?

Comment: There is `strsignal()`, but it shows the description of the signal, not its codename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to `strerror(n)`, there's `strsignal(n)`, which gives the verbose name, like SIGINT -> "Interrupt". But that's not what you really wanted.

This answer on Stackoverflow suggests `sigabbrev_np()` which should be available in glibc 2.32: ​
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481682/6372809

The signal abbreviations, as well as the error number abbreviations are known to the preprocessor, so you could manually build a list like in this answer on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252825/111089

Working on the code there a bit to decrease repetition with the
`#` preprocessor operator, this program would know the names of some signals by number:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define init_signame(x) [x] = #x

static const char *signames[] = {
    init_signame(SIGINT),
    init_signame(SIGSTOP),
    init_signame(SIGTERM),
    init_signame(SIGKILL),
    init_signame(SIGHUP),
    [0] = ""
};

const char *getsig(int sig) {
    if (sig <= 0 || sig >= sizeof(signames) / sizeof(*signames) || !signames[sig])
        return "UNKN";

    return signames[sig];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    if (argc > 1) {
        i = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    printf("%d = %s = %s\n", i, getsig(i), strsignal(i));
}
```

It gives e.g.:

```
$ ./signame2 1
1 = SIGHUP = Hangup
```

The problem here is figuring out all the names to fill out the table...

For that, one option would be to have the compiler dump the defines it knows, e.g.:

```
$ gcc -dM -E - <<< '#include <signal.h>' |grep -E '#define SIG[A-Z]+ ' 
#define SIGBUS 7
#define SIGTTIN 21
#define SIGTTOU 22
...
```

And then use a script to build something useful out of that. Just note that there may also be entries like these:

```
#define SIGCLD SIGCHLD
#define SIGRTMAX (__libc_current_sigrtmax ())
```

And I'm not sure if the real-time signals have individual defines anywhere, or if they're just `SIGRTMIN+0`, `SIGRTMIN+1`, etc. up to `SIGRTMAX`.

Or, at least if you're on Linux, check the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for a list of the signals. The numbers are shuffled between different architectures, and there's slight variation in the signals that exist too, but you can get a list of the names from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have glibc 2.32 or newer you can use [`sigabbrev_np`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigabbrev_np.3.html):

> The sigabbrev_np() function returns the abbreviated name of the signal, sig.  For example, given the value  SIGINT,  it  returns
> the string "INT".

So you just need to prepend `SIG` to get `SIGINT`.

Comment: Curiously, the `kill` sources of my Debian uses an harcoded table which varies with some `#ifdef`.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, there's also a list in the signal(7) man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html A number of them have different numbers depending on the architecture, but of course you can use the #defines to get the actual numbers.

Comment: There's the `perror` command that comes with several database packages. Try `man perror;type perror`, you may already have it.